# Two same arrays but contains method not working

Tags: java, arraylist, contains

I have a SmsClass:

```
public class SmsClass {

private String numberInside;
private String name;


public SmsClass( String numberInside ,String name) {
    this.numberInside = numberInside;
    this.name = name;
}
```

and I try to make two same `ArrayList` of this class:

```
SmsClass SmsClass3 = new SmsClass("name" , "19");
SmsClass SmsClass4 = new SmsClass("name" , "19" );

ArrayList<SmsClass> c1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<SmsClass> c2 = new ArrayList<>();

c1.add(SmsClass1);
c1.add(SmsClass2);
c2.add(SmsClass3);
c2.add(SmsClass4);
```

I have problem with `.contains` method . When I run this code :

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < c1.size() ; i++){
    if (c1.contains(c2.get(i))) {
        System.out.println("victory");
    }
}
```

I have same arrays but nothing found.

Comment: In this case you could actually use `==` for comparing. Other than that you did not override the `equals` method of `SmsClass`.

Answer (score 3):

You should override this equals method like this in `SmsClass`;

```
public class SmsClass {

    private String numberInside;
    private String name;


    public SmsClass(String numberInside, String name) {

        this.numberInside = numberInside;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof SmsClass)) return false;

        SmsClass smsClass = (SmsClass) o;

        if (numberInside != null ? !numberInside.equals(smsClass.numberInside) : smsClass.numberInside != null)
            return false;
        return name != null ? name.equals(smsClass.name) : smsClass.name == null;
    }
}
```

Just an idea,  you can check easily without a `for loop` equations of two list .

```
c1.removeAll(c2);
if (c1.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("victory!");
}
```

Comment: glad to help you. If any post is usefull for your problem totally, approve it.

Answer (score 2):

You must define equals in your Object.
Something like this:

```
public class SmsClass {

private String numberInside;
private String name;


public SmsClass( String numberInside ,String name){

    this.numberInside = numberInside;
    this.name = name;   }

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
   if(obj instanceof SmsClass ) {

            SmsClass smsObj = (SmsClass)obj;
            if(smsObj.getNumberInside() == this.getNumberInside() && 
               smsObj.getName() == this.getName())
                return true;
            }
                return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Your equals method will throw an exception while any other class instance is checkking with this  class.

Comment: Ohh yes dont forget to check if obj is a SmsClass Object. Thanks @drowny

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined `equals` (and implicitly `hashCode`), thus `contains` can not compare your Objects. In case you do not override those both method: `Object::equals` will be used (which just uses reference comparison, via `==`) and `hashCode` (in java-8) will be computed as a pseudo-random number (based on Marsaglia XOR shift algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

Variable names should not start with capital letter as recommendation.

Also, you added `SmsClass1`, and `SmsClass2` to `c1` list, while adding `SmsClass3`, and `SmsClass4` to `c2` list. Although, `smsClass1` and `smsClass3` have same values in their fields,  they are stored on different part of memory. `ArrayList.contains()` method check equality according to elements' references(where they placed in memory).

```
SmsClass SmsClass3 = new SmsClass("name" , "19");
SmsClass SmsClass4 = new SmsClass("name" , "19" );

ArrayList<SmsClass> c1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<SmsClass> c2 = new ArrayList<>();

c1.add(SmsClass1);
c1.add(SmsClass2);
c2.add(SmsClass3);
c2.add(SmsClass4);
```